# junction points on schematics

Tags: schematics, wire

[Website for the wiring](https://www.deviceplus.com/how-tos/building-diy-drone-from-scratch-part-2-using-arduino-nano-as-flight-controller/)

In the schematics circled orange and purple I see a transistor to what I think is connected to a black wire and black and red wires connected to each other. Are these junction points where I have to somehow connect the wires?

I'm a bit confused because with only two endpoints on the wires they all seem to connect together to fit into one pin on the arduino board and I don't see how I might be able to do that

[image]

Comment: It all comes downto the software... in a more compliant eCAD tool such junctions would indication an electrical connection and they would be very clear... this tool? who knows.

Comment: I also used a similar program as you did (DIY Layout Creator). Some people called it (in a negative way) a 'sketch'  (not to be confused with Arduino sketches). However, when I tried to solder everything it was a mess (also because of my bad soldering technique and because wires are 'harder' to solder than components). I spent a few days to learn KiCad and now I'm 'used' to that 'notation' I would never go back. Also, all experienced people can read schematics and PCB layouts and it helps preventing the problem you have.

Comment: That looks like a Fritzing ‘wiring diagram’, where they try to show package pin configuration and wiring on the same sheet. Kind of a hybrid between a schematic and a PCB layout. Is it possible to switch to a schematic view instead of a wiring diagram?

Comment: Oh yeah I believe you're right, they used Fritzing and unfortunately I don't believe I can find the schematic view (https://www.deviceplus.com/how-tos/building-diy-drone-from-scratch-part-2-using-arduino-nano-as-flight-controller/)

Comment: that is not a schematic .... it is a wiring diagram .... it is not a representation of the actual wire routing ... it is only a representation of what connects to what .... use a breadboard to connect multiple wires together ... you could build it same way as the picture, but you would have to solder and insulate the connections

Comment: There are many places in the diagram where you need to connect multiple wires together, In the section you have above the red wires al connect and  also connect to the gray wires that join the transistors.  The red wires also go to multiple places. The diagram on the linked page is very hard to follow and in my opinion badly drawn. I have decades of experience with electronic and I would difficulty following it  - I would have to reverse engineer it and make my own schematic.

Answer (score 3):

In normal schematic drafting, a T intersection implies a connection (junction.) Most CAD tools will also reinforce this by adding a dot to make this clear.

With this tool that looks like MS-Paint? No idea.